# sql data charset / charactter set , set names not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, utf-8, character-encoding

i have the mysql connection below:

```
$dbLink = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '');
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $dbLink);
mysql_select_db('test', $dbLink);
mysql_set_charset('utf-8');
```

it was working fine 1 week ago, but suddenly it is not showing the utf-8 or arabic or unicode contents which are stored in the database. but now even in the database the characters has been changed like `Ø³ÛŒØ¯ Ø§Ø­Ù…Ø¯ Ø´ÛÛŒØ¯ Ú©ÛŒ ØµØ­ÛŒØ­`  and showing in the php the same. before everything was perfect. and the content was showing properly.

even now when i make a new entry in the database its showing fine but something went wrong with the old entries any help please.......

i have tried set names, mysql_set_charset & `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` but nothing happened. please help otherwise my site will be hanged up......

Answer (score 0):

Use MYSQLi because MYSQL is now deprecated.

To set charset utf-8 use mysqli_set_charset() like this:

```
$dbLink = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '');
mysqli_set_charset($dbLink , 'utf8');
mysqli_select_db($dbLink, 'test');
```

If for any reason it is still displaying wrong characters, add this to the beginning of your documents:

```
// Tell PHP that we're using UTF-8 strings until the end of the script
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

// Tell PHP that we'll be outputting UTF-8 to the browser
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
```

**UPDATE**

Select some contents from your database and output the value using `iconv()` and see if it shows the wright charset:

```
<?php

    $dbLink = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '');
    mysqli_set_charset($dbLink , 'utf8');
    mysqli_select_db($dbLink, 'test');

    function get_table_contents(){
        global $dbLink;
        $contents = array();

        $query = "SELECT * FROM ||YOUR TABLE HERE||";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        while($content = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $contents[] = $content;
        }
        return $contents;
    }

    $data = get_table_contents();

?>
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <?php echo iconv(mb_detect_encoding($data[0]['||YOUR COLUMN||'], "UTF-8,ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8", $data[0]['||YOUR COLUMN||']); ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: when i use mysqli and the same query you have given above. it gives me this message.... No such file or directory
it doesnt select or display anything

Comment: @usman610 edited the `html` part. If it still does not display anything do a `print_r($data);` and post here the output

Comment: ok, that is because it isn't retrieving anything from the database, see if the connection is correct with your database-name and table-name

Comment: yes the connection is fine it is working with my code... the one which is given in the question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39132/discussion-between-circle-and-usman610)